# SQL: SELECT value for all rows based on a value in one of the rows and a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a list of total store visits for a customer for a month. The customer has a home store but can visit other stores. Like the table below:

```
MemberId | HomeStoreId | VisitedStoreId | Month | Visits
   1            5               5           1       5           
   1            5               3           1       2           
   1            5               2           1       1           
   1            5               4           1       7
```

I want my select statement to give the number of visits to the home store against each store for that member for that month. Like the below:

```
MemberId | HomeStoreId | VisitedStoreId | Month | Visits | HomeStoreVisits 
   1            5               5           1       5           5
   1            5               3           1       2           5
   1            5               2           1       1           5
   1            5               4           1       7           5
```

I've looked at a SUM with CASE statements inside and OVER with PARTITION but I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Please insert the SQL query you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when homestoreid = visitedstoreid then visits end) over 
           (partition by memberid, month) as homestorevisits
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MemberID,HomestoreID,visitedstoreid,Month,visits, homestorevisits 
FROM Table LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT MemberID, Visits  homestorevisits 
 FROM TABLE WHERE homestoreID =VisitedStoreId 
)T ON T.MemberID = Table.MemberID
```

Comment: Thank you answering. Your post is flagged as "possibly low quality". Could you please try improving it? it is customary to include at least a brief explanation of what you are doing and how it resolves the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a simple subquery.

```
SELECT MemberId, HomeStoreID, VisitedStoreID, Month, Visits,
 (SELECT Visits FROM table t2 
  WHERE t2.MemberId = t1.MemberId
  AND t2.HomeStoreId = t1.HomeStoreId
  AND t2.Month = t1.Month
  AND t2.VisitedStoreId = t2.HomeStoreId) AS HomeStoreVisits
FROM table t1
```